# One slider works but stops the other ones working?

Tags: jquery, html, web, slider, conflict

I'm creating a website for my restaurant.

I had 2 working image sliders in here http://food-ies.fr/livraison-kebab-grillades.html

But when I add a nivo slider and add
 `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`  to the header
 see here http://food-ies.fr/index.html

The image sliders stop!

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: show us how did you initialize nivo object in your html page

Comment: I did exactly like in this tutorial http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/documentation

Comment: check that the second image is exists and its url in correct `http://food-ies.fr/images/diapo_haut/exemple_diapo2.jpg`

Comment: it does not exist yet. but normaly it puts an orange background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this code under the jQuery:

```
<script>
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();   
  // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
  $('someid').hide();
</script>
```

It now works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

.live() calls were removed from jquery 1.9.1 which is nivo uses. nivo will load the first image but .live is used during the swapping of the images.

Search and replace .live in both the jquery.nivo.slider.js and jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js like the following example..

Old: $('a.nivo-nextNav', slider).live('click', (etc.)

New: $(document).on('click', 'a.nivo-nextNav', (etc.)

I came across 2 places in each file that used .live()